Role_ARN issue in GitLab CI/CD with OIDC
I am struggling to find a way to my CI/CD pipeline to use role_arn to retrieve credentials to authenticate to AWS. Below is how I add the role_arn to my current script.
variables: 
 TF_ROOT: "/builds/*companyname*/aws/Live"
  ROLE: ${ROLE_ARN_LIVE}
 AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "eu-west-1"

This is the error I get in the build phase of the pipeline:
If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
$ terraform plan -out=tfplan
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.
╷
│ Error: No valid credential sources found
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on main.tf line 2, in provider "aws":
│    2: provider "aws" {

However, if I use my IAM user access key, secret key and session token, the build step works perfectly. AWS state it is best to use temporary credentials hence why I went down the OIDC route. Link can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html
The script is below and I know Terraform is being phased out in GitLab v18.0 but I would ideally like to get this working using the Terraform template and I can research OpenTofu later.
include:
 - template: Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml  

image: hashicorp/terraform:latest
 
 
variables: 
 TF_ROOT: "/builds/*companyname*/aws/Live"
 ROLE: ${ROLE_ARN_LIVE}
 AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "eu-west-1"

stages:
 - validate
 - test
 - build
 - deploy
 - cleanup

fmt:
  extends: .terraform:fmt
  needs: []
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - terraform fmt -check -recursive

validate:
  extends: .terraform:validate
  needs: []
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - terraform init
    - terraform validate
    

build:
  extends: .terraform:build
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - terraform init
    - terraform plan -out=tfplan
    
   

deploy:
  extends: .terraform:deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - terraform apply 
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME


Using the below script I can retrieve temporary credentials from AWS:

assume role:
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  id_tokens:
    GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN:
      aud: https://gitlab.com
  script:
    - >
      export $(printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s"
      $(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity
      --role-arn ${ROLE_ARN}
      --role-session-name "GitLabRunner-${CI_PROJECT_ID}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
      --web-identity-token ${GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN}
      --duration-seconds 3600
      --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]'
      --output text))
    - aws sts get-caller-identity
  only: 
  - main

below is my merged script and I don't get the same error as above, I get a completely different one at validate stage. Script and error below:
image: hashicorp/terraform:latest

include:
 - template: Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml  

variables: 
 TF_ROOT: "/builds/*companyname*/aws/Live"
 ROLE_ARN_LIVE: ${ROLE_ARN_LIVE}
 AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "eu-west-1"
 IGNORE_TF_DEPRECATION_WARNING: true

stages:
 - assume-role
 - validate
 - build
 - deploy
 - cleanup

assume-role:
  stage: assume-role
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  id_tokens:
    GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN:
      aud: https://gitlab.com
  script:
    - >
      export $(printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s"
      $(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity
      --role-arn ${ROLE_ARN_LIVE}
      --role-session-name "GitLabRunner-${CI_PROJECT_ID}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
      --web-identity-token ${GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN}
      --duration-seconds 3600
      --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]'
      --output text))
    - echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" > ${TF_ROOT}/aws_credentials.env
    - echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" >> ${TF_ROOT}/aws_credentials.env
    - echo "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}" >> ${TF_ROOT}/aws_credentials.env
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ${TF_ROOT}/aws_credentials.env

validate:
  extends: .terraform:validate
  needs: ["assume-role"]
  before_script:
    - source ${TF_ROOT}/aws_credentials.env
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - terraform init
    - terraform validate

build:
  extends: .terraform:build
  needs: ["assume-role"]
  before_script:
    - source ${TF_ROOT}/aws_credentials.env
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - terraform init
    - terraform plan -out=tfplan

deploy:
  extends: .terraform:deploy
  needs: ["build"]
  before_script:
    - source ${TF_ROOT}/aws_credentials.env
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - terraform apply -auto-approve tfplan
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME

Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        host=storage.googleapis.com id=7477539780 responseStatus=200 OK token=glcbt-66
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
Using docker image sha256:f52ae49d6b354b2b9c7b7133e77ee5755a9df368a3df4afd3e628ddedaf717f2 for hashicorp/terraform:latest with digest hashicorp/terraform@sha256:f0821b0019be4a721dcb17ba63e8ee3bfadfb7c0eecf6c739e345d47f135b974 ...
Terraform has no command named "sh". Did you mean "show"?
To see all of Terraform's top-level commands, run:

I can't see where it's getting the step script or the command "sh"

From the CI yaml, the ARN of IAM role is just simple as normal:
variables:
  ROLE_ARN: "arn:aws:iam::${account_id}:role/my-gitlab-oidc"

From the OIDC setting, try to set your aud with your own value and ensure the audience (i.e: my-gitlab) is set inside your IAM identity provider gitlab.com:
id_tokens:
    GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN:
      aud: my-gitlab

From the auth stage, keep the same as your script and ensure that:

Your OIDC token as input, is configured under IAM role trust relationship

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::${account_id}:oidc-provider/gitlab.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "gitlab.com:aud": "my-gitlab"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


Ensure the credentials that you export to the correct artifact path.

From your TF provider aws setup, no need to specify any profile or assume_role, just keep it simple. Once done, from the build stage, can use as follows or your own script:
gitlab-terraform plan


Hi, thank you for your response. Just to clarify:

hard code the role_arn into the script. Is there anything difference between doing it this way and using the CI/CD variables?
Change the aud to my-gitlab.
I should remove assume_role from my script?


It depends on your Git strategy, you can create your own CI env files inside the folder or replace during your pipelines. Make sure the aud value which is the audience is added inside the IAM Identity Provider.

does changing the aud from https://gitlab.com to 'my-gitlab' make a big difference?
